# Destroy user sessions based on user ID

Tags: session, logout

I want to programatically log a specific user out of our WordPress system based on their user ID much like the 'Log Out of All Sessions' button in the WordPress user editor section.

How am I able to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, simple solution after digging in the WordPress code.

```
// get all sessions for user with ID $user_id
$sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance($user_id);

// we have got the sessions, destroy them all!
$sessions->destroy_all();
```

This will log the user with ID `$user_id` out of WordPress.

**Use case:** My use case for this is when a user is approved moderation, but then the situation changes and they are declined, they will be 'kicked' from the system if they have any active login sessions.

Comment: just a question with this. If we were to get all the users in an array, then exclude ourselves from the array (say user id 1), then loop through would that work in the functions.php or would there be a better hook?

Comment: @Ahhhhhhhhhhhhhdfgbv are you wanting to log everyone out of the particular site?

Comment: worked perfectly.  Thank you

Comment: @DebbieKurth - great, glad it's still appropriate, the WordPress codebase hasn't changed too much! :)