# External Authentication, session_tokens not destroyed on logout

Tags: plugin-development, hooks, login, session

There are many questions and [answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53503/can-i-programmatically-login-a-user-without-a-password) on external authentication and some code prior to WordPress 4.0 need some tweaking to get them to work. For example, adding a fourth parameter to the `wp_set_auth_cookie` will stop some strange issues. However, session_tokens are not destroyed and the meta value is repeatedly added to after each login (leading to a huge mess).

To get WordPress caching plugins to work properly, then the session_tokens need to work properly: created on login and destroyed on logout.

The following code will login any user in the external database.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'xenword_login', 10, 1 );

function xenword_login( $username ) {

add_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );    // hook in earlier than other callbacks to short-circuit them
$user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $username ) );
remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10 );

    if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, is_ssl(), true );

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        return $user->ID;
    }
}

return false;
}
```

Then an allow_programmatic_login is placed in the same file.

```
function allow_programmatic_login( $user, $username, $password ) {

    $visitor = XenWord::getVisitor();
    $user_id = XenWord::getVisitor()->getUserId();

    if ( $user_id > 0 ) {
        $username = $visitor['username'];
        return get_user_by( 'login', $username );
    }
}
```

Fantastic except an administrator, editor, etc cannot go to the dashboard because the cookie will not be validated. Replacing the `wp_validate_auth_cookie` will get the accounts to have access but then caching plugins will not load properly.

After tinkering for a few days (year), I discovered recently that the `verify( $token )` causes the issue.

```
$manager = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user->ID );
if ( ! $manager->verify( $token ) ) {
    do_action( 'auth_cookie_bad_session_token', $cookie_elements );
    return false;
}
```

This led me to look at the database and see that the session_tokens were being created on login but not destroyed on logout.

My question: Has anyone identified and overcome this issue because simply using the following logs in the account but no session_tokens are created.

```
    wp_clear_auth_cookie();
    wp_set_current_user( $user_id, $user->user_login );
    wp_set_auth_cookie( $user_id, true, is_ssl(), true );

    do_action('wp_login', $user->user_login );
```

This leaves me using the authenticate option but the session_tokens are not destroyed. Any suggestions?

Comment: Get all session tokens of user: 
`$sessions = WP_Session_Tokens::get_instance( $user_id );` 

Destroy them all: 
`$sessions->destroy_all();` Maybe this will work. :-) **[SOURCE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184161/destroy-user-sessions-based-on-user-id)**

Comment: Your shor tcircuiting WP normal authentication process and handling it yourself.  My recommendation is to remove the after_setup_theme hook, remove xenword_login function, only have remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10 ); and the allow_programmatic_login() function.  Stop playing around with WP cookies.

Comment: As stated session_tokens in usermeta are not being destroyed on logout. This leads to many issues. I'm simply trying to get external authentication to work - and linked in OP to the page with different answers. None work. Maybe someone who has actually tried external authentication since 4.2 can answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code to get sessions to write to the usermeta and delete on logout. This code works with WordPress 4.5.2. The code is for user_id information only.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'new_login' );

function new_login() {

    $user_id = ''; // Change your code to grab user_id from external source

    if ( $user_id > 0 && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $user = get_user_by( 'id', $user_id );

        wp_clear_auth_cookie();
        wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );
        wp_set_auth_cookie( $user->ID, true, is_ssl() );

        if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
            return true;
        }

    } elseif ( $user_id == 0 && is_user_logged_in() ) {
        wp_logout();
        wp_set_current_user( 0 );
    }
}
```

There are a couple of key issues. First, the conditional `! is_user_logged_in()` must be included with the check for a `user_id` greater than zero. Next, the `wp_set_current_user(0)` must follow the `wp_logout()` in order to avoid a refresh.

I hope this helps others trying to get external authentication working with user_id information only.