# How to Request a User to Register on Landing at a Site, Then Automatically Delete the Users Password on Logout?

Tags: php, plugin-development, functions

I have am trying to get my head around building the following functionality into a business information website that is not an eCommerce site or a Blog:

1. All site Visitors must register on landing, in order to view/access the Home page and any subsequent pages on the site.
2. The Visitor's password must be deleted as soon as they end their session and they logout. In other words the password has a "One Time Use". This would require the Visitor register a New Password if they return to the site at a point in the future.
3. The Visitor's details are stored and their subsequent visits for re-registration are tracked.

Any help or advice from the experienced members of this forum would be sincerely appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `auth_cookie` filter to set an expiration time of 0. This will make sure that the cookie is only valid for the current browser session.

For password expiration you can use a plugin like: https://wordpress.org/plugins/expire-passwords/

Pls also see: [Destroy user sessions based on user ID](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184161/destroy-user-sessions-based-on-user-id)

Comment: Thank you Shivanand. I'll give this a go and report back on my progress.

Comment: Unfortunately, the plugin 'expire-passwords' doesn't work in hours and minutes, only days, weeks and years. I found the same issue with the plugin, 'expire-users'. Sadly, I can't figure out how to modify the auth-cookie filter. My knowledge is not sufficient.